# SharePoint 2013 search filters on left side

Tags: search, enterprise-search, search-scope

When I search for anything on the main page, I am brought to a page with search results.  On the left side of the page, I am able to "filter" by document type (i.e. PPT, PDF, Excel, etc.), author and date created.  How can I add more filters to the left side based upon columns I created in the document library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Out of the box ossearch.aspx is not editable. Create a Search center and configure your refiners there.

Give some time and try to understand how SharePoint enterprise search center works . [This](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/10/29/set-up-a-search-center-in-sharepoint-2013/) could be an appropriate tutorial. From there on you will learn in [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/11/10/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013/) article how to map(index) your document's meta data properties in admin center and use them as refiners on Search results page later.

Comment: Thank you!  I have a follow up question... should I be finding it this difficult to create a sharepoint enterprise search center?  I am not a coder but not entirely a novice..  I created the search center site but am not convinced I have to do all the reindexing or crawling that the directions indicate are required.  Do I?

Comment: You don't need to know as such any programming for this. Just follow the tutorials. If you are working over SharePoint 2013 online version then automatic(continuous)  crawls happen frequently which automatically index your columns. You just have to be sure you have mapped your custom columns in the admin center against refinable strings.

Answer (score 3):

Those are called refiners. You can customize these by editing the page. Click the gear icon and select Edit page.

Tick the down arrow on the refinement web part and select Edit Web Part. In the web part properties, click the Choose Refiners button and add in any refiners you want. OK out as necessary and save the page.

If your fields aren't showing up, then it is possible they haven't been indexed yet, or they need to be mapped to a refinable property.

Comment: I have site collection administrator rights, but when I search for something from the home page, and go to the search results page, I am don't have "edit page" as an option on the gear icon... any thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: Is your search results page residing in your site collection, or is it taking you to an enterprise search center?

Comment: It searches "This Site" first, then "Everything".  If I remove the "Everything" option, will I have a chance to edit the research results page?